# Django JSON file to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, django, pandas

I have a simple json in Django. I catch the file with this command `data = request.body` and i want to convert it to pandas datarame

JSON:

`{ "username":"John", "subject":"i'm good boy", "country":"UK","age":25}`

I already tried pandas read_json method and json.loads from json library but it didn't work.

Comment: It didntt work!

Comment: if i send the JSON with this formation it works:

[{ "username":"John", "subject":"i'm good boy", "country":"UK", "age":25 }]

but i want to catch it without the array []

Comment: Add your code so it will be easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `pd.DataFrame.from_records()` when you have json or dictonary

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([ json ]) OR df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([ dict. ])`

or

you need to provide iterables for pandas dataframe:

`e.g. df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':[ values ],'column_2':[ values ]})`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
json = { "username":"John", "subject":"i'm good boy", "country":"UK", "age":25 }
print (pd.DataFrame(json, index=[0]))
   age country       subject username
0   25      UK  i'm good boy     John
```

Or:

```
print (pd.DataFrame([json]))
   age country       subject username
0   25      UK  i'm good boy     John
```

EDIT:

If input is `file` and get `error`:

```
s = pd.read_json('file.json')
```

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

is necessary add `typ=Series` and then convert [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
s = pd.read_json('file.json', typ='series')
print (s)
age                   25
country               UK
subject     i'm good boy
username            John
dtype: object

df = s.to_frame().T
print (df)
  age country       subject username
0  25      UK  i'm good boy     John
```

Comment: Ok, what is `type(json)` ?

Comment: It is interesting if work `[{ "username":"John", "subject":"i'm good boy", "country":"UK", "age":25 }]` - I think with `pd.DataFrame(json)`. But without `[]` you need `pd.DataFrame([json])` - added `[]` to variable `json`

Comment: it is a simple json that every web platform use to send information to one webservice to another. I use POST method to send it and catch it. What do you mean with what  type(json)??? If i use this command my web service doesnt return anython.

Comment: @jezrael it returns me just '0'. it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Sorry, I try explain more. I am not django user, but if assign output to variable `x` by `x = some code what return json` there is possible use `type(x)`

Comment: Maybe need `print (pd.DataFrame([data]))`